# Print html from mobile browser using network printer ip address by jquery

Tags: jquery, printing

I want to print an HTML receipt from the browser JQuery, using the IP address of the network printer.
Is it possible to send the print documents to the printer using JQuery from the browser directly without involving backend any language?